# How to commit the Objects till the point of time when you have Persistence exception

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am trying a simple application with the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public classJPAConfiguration()
{
 @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        Properties databaseProperties = datamodelConfigurationService.getDatabaseConfiguration();
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource(databaseProperties));
        em.setPackagesToScan(Objects.requireNonNull(databaseProperties.getProperty("scan.packages","com.microfocus.zenworks.kafka.objects")));
        
        
        final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        
        return em;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(Properties databaseProperties)
    {
        Properties c3p0Properties = datamodelConfigurationService.getC3P0Configuration();
        
        final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try
        {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(Objects.requireNonNull(databaseProperties.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        }
        catch(PropertyVetoException e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception setting driver class", e);
        }
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(databaseProperties.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUser(Objects.requireNonNull(databaseProperties.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Objects.requireNonNull(databaseProperties.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));
        
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(c3p0Properties.getProperty("c3p0.initial-pool-size", "5")));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(c3p0Properties.getProperty("c3p0.max-pool-size", "20")));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(c3p0Properties.getProperty("c3p0.min-pool-size", "5")));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
    
    
    final Properties additionalProperties()
    {
        return datamodelConfigurationService.getHibernateConfiguration();
    }
}
```

and a dao with the following api where the persistence context is inject

```
public class GenericDAO()
{
@PersistenceContext(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Transactional
    public List<T> update(List<T> entityList) throws ProcessingException
    {
        
        int index = 0;
        try
        {
            List<T> updatedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            logger.info("Merging the objects in batch started ");
            for(T entity : entityList)
            {
                index++;
                T persistedObject = entityManager.merge(entity);
                updatedObjects.add(persistedObject);
            }
    
            logger.info("Merging the objects in batch completed ");
            return updatedObjects;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ProcessingException(e, index);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now the use case is,I want to persist some objects say 100 out of which 10th one throws persistence exception . Is there any way where I can commit till 9  and return the exception back  to the caller ?

I tried same and I get the following exception

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

I am new to spring and any suggestions/pointers are welcome.

Thanks,
Rajasekhar

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception you get ? By default Spring doesn't rollback in case of checked Exception. In case of RuntimeException, you can use the attribute noRollbackFor.

```
@Transactional (noRollbackFor=ProcessingException.class)
```

Comment: I tried to debug and I found that code which commit the data fails with the exception I mentioned here .
     TransactionAspectSupport-> completeTransactionAfterThrowing

if (txInfo.transactionAttribute != null && txInfo.transactionAttribute.rollbackOn(ex)) {
    try {
     txInfo.getTransactionManager().rollback(txInfo.getTransactionStatus());
    }

else {
    // We don't roll back on this exception.
    // Will still roll back if TransactionStatus.isRollbackOnly() is true.
    try {
     txInfo.getTransactionManager().commit(txInfo.getTransactionStatus());
    }